# Is there a policy about political messages in usernames?

Tags: discussion, policy, usernames

Is there a policy about political messages in usernames?

Of course the answer should be the same regardless of whether I agree with the message.

The question applies in general.  This time it was prompted by the username `Tiago supports GoFundMonica`.

Comment: [There are __a lot__ of people, just on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?page=1&tab=reputation&filter=month&search=reinstate) currently who modified their names to include something about that topic.

Comment: There is a related discussion on meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339999/273494

Comment: this question should be closed because it is answered at meta stack exchange https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340087

Comment: To the last commenter with the offensive political handle: nonsense. Someone with a reputation of 1 has posted an answer, and the poster has accepted it. That in no way makes it policy. See my comment to that answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no rules specific to EL&U regarding usernames.

Over on main Meta I could find 3 possible prohibitions:

- [offensive usernames](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117596/possibly-offensive-usernames)
- [usernames with weird characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274129/can-user-names-have-a-filter-on-whacky-chars)
- [usernames as advertising](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61249/usernames-as-advertising-or-spam)

The basic guidelines seem to be:

- If you find a username offensive, flag it and a mod will deal with it at their discretion.
- Weird characters in usernames would be actively prohibited if developer time allowed, but there's no need to flag usernames with such characters unless you find it offensive.
- Advertising in usernames is acceptable. A username is essentially treated as part of the profile for this content.

So with regard to "Tiago supports GoFundMonica", that name seems to fall under "it's OK on the profile, so OK in the username."

There was a period where actual [links to Monica's GoFundMe were deleted from profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338270/why-is-se-removing-links-and-community-ads-about-legal-issues), but I'm not sure of SE's stance on simply mentioning it. Until they say one way or another I will assume it's fine.

As [ColleenV commented](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13536/is-there-a-policy-about-political-messages-in-usernames#comment57251_13536), there is an [SE meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339999/273494) on this subject.